# Why Python3 platform.processor on import platform give an empty output?

Tags: python

Using python3 on linux, import platform, platform processor give an empty response
comparing with cpuinfo, it give all information.

Why?

Is there a way to correct that and get information from platform module?

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import platform
>>> platform.processor()
''
>>> 


>>> import cpuinfo
>>> cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()
{'python_version': '3.7.3.final.0 (64 bit)', 'cpuinfo_version': [7, 0, 0], 'cpuinfo_version_string': '7.0.0', 'arch': 'X86_64', 'bits': 64, 'count': 4, 'arch_string_raw': 'x86_64', 'vendor_id_raw': 'GenuineIntel', 'brand_raw': 'Intel(R) C\
ore(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz', 'hz_advertised_friendly': '2.5000 GHz', 'hz_actual_friendly': '3.1005 GHz', 'hz_advertised': [2500000000, 0], 'hz_actual': [3100537000, 0], 'stepping': 9, 'model': 142, 'family': 6, 'flags': ['3dnowprefetc\
h', 'abm', 'acpi', 'adx', 'aes', 'aperfmperf', 'apic', 'arat', 'arch_perfmon', 'art', 'avx', 'avx2', 'bmi1', 'bmi2', 'bts', 'clflush', 'clflushopt', 'cmov', 'constant_tsc', 'cpuid', 'cpuid_fault', 'cx16', 'cx8', 'de', 'ds_cpl', 'dtes64', \
'dtherm', 'dts', 'epb', 'ept', 'ept_ad', 'erms', 'est', 'f16c', 'flexpriority', 'flush_l1d', 'fma', 'fpu', 'fsgsbase', 'fxsr', 'ht', 'hwp', 'hwp_act_window', 'hwp_epp', 'hwp_notify', 'ibpb', 'ibrs', 'ida', 'intel_pt', 'invpcid', 'invpcid_\
single', 'lahf_lm', 'lm', 'mca', 'mce', 'mmx', 'monitor', 'movbe', 'mpx', 'msr', 'mtrr', 'nonstop_tsc', 'nopl', 'nx', 'osxsave', 'pae', 'pat', 'pbe', 'pcid', 'pclmulqdq', 'pdcm', 'pdpe1gb', 'pebs', 'pge', 'pln', 'pni', 'popcnt', 'pse', 'p\
se36', 'pti', 'pts', 'rdrand', 'rdrnd', 'rdseed', 'rdtscp', 'rep_good', 'sdbg', 'sep', 'sgx', 'smap', 'smep', 'ss', 'ssbd', 'sse', 'sse2', 'sse4_1', 'sse4_2', 'ssse3', 'stibp', 'syscall', 'tm', 'tm2', 'tpr_shadow', 'tsc', 'tsc_adjust', 't\
sc_deadline_timer', 'tscdeadline', 'vme', 'vmx', 'vnmi', 'vpid', 'x2apic', 'xgetbv1', 'xsave', 'xsavec', 'xsaveopt', 'xsaves', 'xtopology', 'xtpr'], 'l3_cache_size': 3145728, 'l2_cache_size': 262144, 'l1_data_cache_size': 32768, 'l1_instr\
uction_cache_size': 32768, 'l2_cache_line_size': 256, 'l2_cache_associativity': 6}
```

Comment: [An empty string is returned if the value cannot be determined. Note that many platforms do not provide this information or simply return the same value as for `machine()`. NetBSD does this.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.processor)

Comment: Thanks, I have missed that part of the documentation.
But, do you know a way to for the platform module to get that information?

Comment: `platform.processor()` (platform architecture) and `cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()` (essentially a parsed `/proc/cpuinfo`) are different data entirely and not really related

Comment: It was just to demonstrate that the information exist and is available but not from the other module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(current cpython implementation details)

on linux platforms, the lookup for `platform.processor` subprocesses to `uname -p` -- so whatever result you're getting from `uname` will be there:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dd18001c308fb3bb65006c91d95f6639583a3420/Lib/platform.py#L758-L769

in your case, `uname -p` is probably returning the empty string for whatever reason

note that `cpuinfo` (essentially a parse of `/proc/cpuinfo`) is unrelated to `platform.processor()` which is the information reported by the platform

you might be looking for `platform.architecture()` which is much more reliable way to retrieve the processor architecture

or if `cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()` contains the information you're looking for, why not use that?

or if you don't want an additional dependency, parse `/proc/cpuinfo` (though that's not portable to non-linuxes)

Comment: uname -p return unknown

Comment: >>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'ELF')